# Is there a direct/indirect detection for the homogeneity of the Universe?

Tags: cosmology, astrophysics, cosmic-microwave-background

I know that for mathematical simplicity the Universe is assumed to be isotropic and homogeneous (the cosmological principle).

The isotropy of the universe, and correct me if I'm wrong, is confirmed from the isotropy of CMB and its assumed that the Universe evolved the same way hence its isotropic now (not only at the last scattering surface). This isotropy together with the principle that there is no preferred position in the Universe (the Copernicus principle) implies the homogeneity of the Universe.

Is there any observational clue for that homogeneity?

Comment: Galactic distribution surveys like 2dFGRS https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2dF_Galaxy_Redshift_Survey?

Comment: I'm not sure how it confirms the homogeneity. Thanks though.

Comment: It's about as direct a measurement as one can make by measuring the 3d coordinates of each galaxy. Or are you unsure if the universe is really homogeneous? It's not really smooth, that's true.

Comment: I just think that it doesn't proof the homogeneity of the Universe.

Comment: @maha there are no proofs in physics. There are validations. The data are consistent with the universe being homogeneous at a level of 10^-6, look at the errors https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Cmbr.svg . The hypothesis of a homogeneous universe is consistent with the data

Comment: In fact, the universe is not homogeneous, that's why we're here. So there is proof all around us that it is *in*homogeneous (at some level).

Comment: *The* answer is in measuring the spatial distribution of galaxies. You've twice rejected that answer, so it would help if you told us what definition of "homogeneity" you are using.

Comment: @anna I understand that CMB act like  "perfect black body radiation" which in favor of the validation  ":) thanks" of the Big Bang theory. Now if it's used also to prove the homogeneity, please clarify the link more.

Comment: @Chris White my problem is that I think that the validation is for the isotropy, or there is something I'm missing? Well .. I understand that from the CMB sky image that isotropy is shown and I guessed that the redshift only enhances it, right? If not I'd like more help to understand the comments since my background isn't coming from astrophysics and just started  cosmology.

Comment: @CuriousOne I'm stuck at the point that homogeneity is validated by two things together :the isotropy  and the principle that there is no preferred position in the Universe. And I think the link is a proof for the isotropy,  is it clear from the link that any other galaxy can picture the Universe as we did (which is other equivalent def for the homogeneity)? (It might be clear and obvious but as I said..I'm just stuck :/ )

Comment: You need to go to the mathematics department if you are looking for proofs. There are none in physics. We only have observational evidence. The measurement validates more than just isotropy since the distances can also be measured, albeit with limited accuracy. As I and Rob Jeffries pointed out, the universe is not that homogeneous, nor does it have to be. The assumption that it's homogeneous is not particularly critical to cosmology, we can easily incorporate biases into it and see where those lead us, if they ever show up in the data.

Comment: @maha Nothing in physics measurements is absolute, and the measure of homogeneity is dependent on a number, i.e. at what differences  the homogeneity  disappears and hills and valleys appear in the plot. It is written in the caption of the  plot  https://commons.wikimedia.org  "This image shows a temperature range of ± 200 microKelvin." The black body temperature of the CMB is  2.7260±0.0013 K so the error bars in the curve are of order 10^-6

Comment: the error bars of the CMB black body curve